# So I've signed up to contribute to the blog. Now what?

Tags: support, blog

I've decided to [contribute to the Home Improvement Blog](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/494/33). I've registered with WordPress and Trello, and I'm ready to write my first blog post.  What do I do now?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, Thank you for choosing to contribute to the DIY StackExchange Blog.

Because this is a community blog, the procedure for publishing a post is a bit more complex than with a personal blog.  As such, we ask that you please follow the steps below when creating posts.

## Come up with a good idea for a blog post.

This is often times the most difficult and time consuming part of the process. Remember entries do not have to be long epic novels, short descriptions of projects you've completed (with pictures of course) can be even more awesome.

## Start writing the post.

- Log in to Word Press and click ***Add New*** -> ***Post***.
- Write the post.
- You can save your progress any time by clicking ***Save Draft*** (please **DO NOT** click ***Publish***).

## Get your post reviewed.

Once you have finished writing your post, you can submit it to be reviewed by other members of the community (this is currently optional, but encouraged).

- In Word Press, assign the ***Ready for Review*** category to the post.
- In [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111/home-improvement), post a link to the preview of the post you've written, and ask for a review.

## Ready to publish... almost

Once a post has been reviewed, the reviewer will assign the ***Ready to Publish*** category to the post in Word Press.

A publish date will then be selected for the post.

On the selected day the post will be published, and will be available for public consumption at http://diy.blogoverflow.com/.

---

Again, Thank you for participating in the DIY StackExchange blog.

#### NOTES:

- Remember this is a community blog, and posts are published on a schedule. We have to take turns publishing posts, so please **DO NOT** publish posts yourself.  All posts will be published for you, by an administrator, on the appropriate date
- To ensure we always have fresh posts, we are currently on a 1-a-week schedule.  This means that your posts will likely have to wait to be published, we understand that this can be frustrating.  We will do our best to make sure posts are published as quickly as possible.  As more contributors join in we should be able to increase the publish rate, so posts will be published sooner.  Until that time, we thank you for your patience and understanding.